# How to find $R$ such that $\prod_{p\mid q} \Big(p-2-r +O\left( \frac{1}{p-2}\right) \Big)=\prod_{p\mid q} (p-2-r) +O(R)$.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

suppose $q$ a square free integer (so that $\prod_{p\mid q} p =q$). Let $r$ be a positive integer, and assume that $q$ is not divisible by any prime less than or equal to $r+2$.

Now, suppose that I have
$\prod_{p\mid q} \Big(p-2-r +O\left( \frac 1 {p-2}\right) \Big)$. I want to express this in terms in $\prod_{p|q} (p-2-r).$

i.e. I want to find $R$ such that
$\prod_{p\mid q} \Big(p-2-r +O\left( \frac{1}{p-2}\right) \Big)=\prod_{p\mid q} (p-2-r) +O(R)$.

How do I find $R$?

Thanks

Comment: As stated this doesn't make sense: $p$ is being used both as an independent variable and as the indexing variable of all the products. In addition, do you want to assume that all of the primes dividing $q$ are large, perhaps bigger than $r+2$, so that none of the terms in the product are negative? You should certainly be assuming that $q$ is odd if you have $O(\frac1{p-2})$....

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin. I edited my question. Hope this helps

Comment: You might as well simplify the statement by replacing $r+2$ with $r$, and $O(\frac1{p-2})$ with $O(\frac1p)$.

Comment: One can certainly take $R=q$. Is that sufficient for you? If not, what properties do you need $R$ to satisfy? Does this have to work for every choice of $r$, or just large choices or just small choices...?

Comment: Yes I think $R=q$ would be good enough. How do I get that @GregMartin ?